# Non-Static Generic function that invokes a method passed in as a parameter

Tags: java, generics, java-7

I'm trying to consolidate 2 methods into 1, because they handle exceptions the same way. I know in C# you can pass functions/actions as parameters into other functions. I tried creating a generic method to invoke a function, but can't seem to figure it out.

```
public String getTheStuff(String client) {
    try {
        return extService.getProduct(client);
    } catch (UIException e) {
        notHealthy();
    } catch (HostException e) {
        notHealthy();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Throwables.propagate(e);
    }
}

public CustomType getsomeMoreStuff(String source, int offset) {
    try {
        return extService.getMetrics(source, offset);
    } catch (UIException e) {
        notHealthy();
    } catch (HostException e) {
        notHealthy();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Throwables.propagate(e);
    }
}
```

What I'm looking for is something like

```
public T invokeExtService(Function functionToInvoke, Parameters[] params){
    try {
        return functionToInvoke.Invoke(params);
    } catch (UIException e) {
        notHealthy();
    } catch (HostException e) {
        notHealthy();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Throwables.propagate(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can with reflection, but the awkwardness of doing it with reflection would be more trouble than just having the two methods the way you have now.

Comment: That said, you can combine the `UIException` and `HostException` handling into one catch block: `catch (UIException | HostException e) { notHealthy(); }`

Comment: (If it was Java 8, it'd be a slightly different story, but you explicitly tagged Java 7.
)

Comment: @LouisWasserman yeah our platform is still on Java 7 :(

Comment: @shmosel I was planning to have a multi-catch but we might end up handling the exceptions differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @LouisWasserman said, this would be much nicer in Java 8, but how about something like this (untested):

```
public <T> T invoke(Callable<T> function) {
    try {
        return function.call();
    } catch (UIException e) {
        notHealthy();
    } catch (HostException e) {
        notHealthy();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Throwables.propagate(e);
    }
}

public String getTheStuff(final String client) {
    return invoke(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() {
            return extService.getProduct(client);
        }
    });
}

public CustomType getsomeMoreStuff(final String source, final int offset) {
    return invoke(new Callable<CustomType>() {
        @Override
        public CustomType call() {
            return extService.getMetrics(source, offset);
        }
    });
}
```

To be honest, I'm not sure how worthwhile this is considering how short your methods are (and they could be even shorter with [multi-catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html#multiple)).